# Hibernate Unsupported tuple comparison combination error in @Query after spring boot 2.x to 3.x migration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've migrated from spring boot `2.7` to `3.2.2` and have following method on one of repositories which was working in 2.7.

```
@Query(
    """
        SELECT new com.domain.services.resources.repository.AllocationChainResult(\
        aca.allocationChain.id, aca.allocationChain.name, aca.referencedEntityId, aca.referencedEntityType, \
        aca.referencedRestrictionEntityId, aca.referencedRestrictionEntityType, aca.timeModel.id) \
        FROM AllocationChainAssignment AS aca \
        WHERE aca.referencedEntityId IN :refEntityIds \
        AND aca.deleted = 'active' \
        AND ((aca.timeModel = null) \
        OR (EXISTS \
        (SELECT tma.timeModelId FROM TimeModelAvailability AS tma \
        WHERE tma.timeModelId = aca.timeModel.id \
        AND tma.timeFrom <= :timestamp \
        AND tma.timeTo > :timestamp)))\
        """
)
List<AllocationChainResult> findUsingReferencedEntityIds(
    @Param("refEntityIds") Set<String> entityIds,
    @Param("timestamp") Long timestamp
);
```

To be honest I don't know what to change/fix in it because that error message is not very helpful.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported tuple comparison combination. LHS is neither a tuple nor a tuple subquery but RHS is a tuple: org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.ComparisonPredicate@76dba376
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitRelationalPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7750)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.ComparisonPredicate.accept(ComparisonPredicate.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitGroupedPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6952)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.GroupedPredicate.accept(GroupedPredicate.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitJunctionPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7348)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitJunction(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7326)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.Junction.accept(Junction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitGroupedPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6952)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.GroupedPredicate.accept(GroupedPredicate.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitJunctionPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7348)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitJunction(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7329)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.Junction.accept(Junction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitWhereClause(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3236)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3182)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:861)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137)
```

does anybody has some idea what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and found it was caused by a `= null`.
Replacing it with `is null` fixed the problem for me.